# how can I enable a specific debug output in ruby?

Tags: ruby, debugging

I want to write a script in ruby. The goal of the script
is to automate the build process of a cmake project.
I want to add a lot of debug out but if I use puts or
print the output will always be visible and I don't want that.

I want to do something like
my_script --debug $foo

and to have output related with the development of the script.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You should try out Logger.

```
require 'logger'

$log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
$log.level = Logger::DEBUG

$log.debug "Sample debug message"
$log.info "Sample info message"
$log.error "Sample error message"
```

You only need to change one line to decide which messages should be printed (i.e. `$log.level = Logger::DEBUG`). Alternatively, you can parse the command line options to set the Logger level.

If you think the output is too verbose, you can redefine it like so:

```
class Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp} #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

Comment: So,is it possible to make ruby to print all
the Logger::INFO messages but not the Logger::DEBUG ones?

Comment: @terietor Yep, the [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) levels are `FATAL`, `ERROR`, `WARN`, `INFO` and `DEBUG`. If you raise the level to `INFO`, you won't get the debug messages, and if you raise it to `ERROR`, you'll only get errors and fatal errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)

By setting the level of logging like this

```
log.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

you can manage to print out or not print out the debug messages.

Also you can choose the output stream, it could be console or file like this

```
log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```